# Can I interact with a Windows.Form application on a non-interactive desktop session?

Tags: winforms

I'd like to schedule a task that is a program that launches another program.  The other program is a Windows.Form application.

Is it possible to programmatically interact with a Windows.Form application on a non-interactive desktop session?

Specifically, because I know this sounds very odd, I'd like to launch SpaceSniffer or something similar, and provide some interaction with it.

Comment: can you clarify - a scheduled task opens an app, that then opens a Winform application. The Winform application will then launch other tools that you wish to interact with? in what way do you expect to be able interact - I idn't see any API info with SpaceSniffer so are you talking about simulating mouse clicks??

Comment: In fashion, hopefully we'll get an answer to the question in about 18  -24 months; but I am talking about being able to SendKeys() or mouse clicks, yes.

Comment: in my experience that would be quite unreliable and really hard to test, better off finding a product with an API :)

Comment: I would try to find an alternative program that has an API (i.e. can be used as a library), or has command-line parameters that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

No, well it's not a good idea, anyway.  Call a program with an API or a command line interface.

Comment: This would be for programs with no API or command line interface.  This is why I posed the question.